# What 2 Mips assembly instructions would induce exactly 2 stalls?

Tags: assembly, mips, forwarding, instruction-set

I am using the Mips instruction set architecture and the WinMips64 simulator.

My question is when forwarding is deactivated what 2 instructions would produce the 2 stalls, and then when forwarding is enabled produce 0.

I would also like to know how instructions pass through the Mips pipeline when forwarding is enabled.

Comment: I guess you've read MIPS manuals and they do not answer your question

Comment: Have a look a slides 6 and 7 [here](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse378/07au/lectures/L13-Stalls-And-Flushes.ppt) for an example (a better source is probably available if you search a little harder)